# Django, ImportError: cannot import name Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

Why is this happening?
My celery.py:

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myshop.settings')

app = Celery('myshop')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

my **init**.py

```
# import celery
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

I even tried renaming celery.py to something else and the error still persisted. Could it be because of my python version?

Comment: Do you have in your __init__.py this line: `from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals`

Comment: @sebb Turns out I had not. I have added it now as you suggested, but it gives an error saying  `Task orders.tasks.order_created[719e5c25-b8df-41ad-95bd-6c432d82566e] raised unexpected: error(61, 'Connection refused')`

Comment: Did you start your worker ? Do you have Redis or RabbitMQ running ?

Comment: @sebb yes , and I have RabbitMQ running

Comment: Can you show your settings file ?

Comment: Here's the code:  https://pastebin.com/ggWurjY8

Comment: You do not have Rabbit settings. You did not set up your broker.

Comment: @sebb But I had downloaded Rabbit from their site, and started it using the code `rabbitmq-server`. It is running ? : https://i.imgur.com/dV3FfBa.png

Comment: But you haven't done anything to tell Celery that you've done so, or where to find it.

Comment: But how does your application should know which brooker to use ? If you have connection refused you either have it running on different port or your app cannot see the brooker.  Just refer to http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Answer (score 2):

I`ll post answer in order to move it from comments.

First of all in your __ init__.py file add this line

`from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals`

Second of all you need to add to your settings, information about brooker. 
This is an example configuration file to get you started. It should contain all you need to run a basic Celery set-up.

### Broker settings.

`broker_url = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'`

The next thing is running your celery worker. So if you celery app is named `myshop` you have to run celery worker (using your environment), by typing this simple command:

`celery -A myshop worker -l info`

Then try to run your task, and everything should be fine.

Comment: Hi , I added `from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals` to my init file, added `broker_url = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"` to my settings.py file and ran `celery -A myshop worker -l info` with rabbitMQ running but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: What port is your RabbitMQ running on ?

Comment: Documentation says:

PORT 15672 for RabbitMQ version 3.x
PORT 55672 for RabbitMQ pre 3.x

Comment: How do I check what Port my RabbitMQ is running on?

Comment: For example when you have your rabbit running type in in console: 

`ps aux | grep rabbit ` 

You should be able to see what port it is using

Answer (score -1):

its becuase of version

How u have installed celery

pip install celery==3.0.19
if this
then run python by
**python manage.py runserver**
or
pip3 install celery==3.0.19
if this
then run python by
**python3 manage.py runserver**